# sql server parse column and insert into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have a column with both chars and numbers that are separated by an Underscore

**Ex: PI (column Name) = ID_32,ID_43,ID_03**

I also created a new column called UniqueColumn. In this column I just want the numbers that are in the PI column

therefore it should look like this: UniqueColumn=32,43,03

My code thus far:

```
UPDATE table
  SET UniqueColumn = RIGHT(PI,LEN(PI)-CHARINDEX('_',PI));


select top 10 dbo.table.UniqueColumn from dbo.table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET UniqueColumn = substring(PI, charindex('_',PI)+1, len(PI));
```

Use `charindex` to find the `_` and then use `substring` to get the result.

Comment: That only works for the first value. I got this output : "32,ID_43,ID_03"

Answer (score 0):

If the characters on the left of the underscore are always "ID", then you could use the Replace() function.

```
Update table
Set UniqueColumn = Replace(PI,'ID_','')
```

If the characters are not always specifically 'ID' then something like this may work:

```
DECLARE @UQ as varchar(50)
DECLARE TblCursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT PI FROM testTable
OPEN tblCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor INTO @UQ
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        WHILE CHARINDEX('_',@UQ)>0
            BEGIN
                SET @UQ = LEFT(@UQ,PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%',@UQ)-1) + RIGHT(@UQ,LEN(@UQ)-CHARINDEX('_',@UQ))
            END
        UPDATE testTable
        SET UniqueColumn = @UQ
        WHERE CURRENT OF tblCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor
    END
CLOSE tblCursor
DEALLOCATE tblCursor
GO
```

Result:

```
PI                   UniqueColumn 
ID_32,ID_43,ID_03    32,43,03
```